How do you manage shared python libraries across applications/scripts on the same server? How do you handle imports and how to manage version control?
I have a few python libraries I am developing at my job to access different internal tools.  I am coming across two main issues I could use some assistance on.

Using the shared modules across scripts/apps. If I want to use the modules across different scripts/libraries, how would I handle updating it once I install them with pip under a specific virtual env/global modules? In my example I have a django app that will use certain modules and then again some stand alone scripts may use it.

Version control - I currently am attempting to track the files in bitbucket. If these scripts will use shared instances of these modules. How do I handle making changes to the module and then pushing them to the server? Do I have to login to the server and pull the new code and reinstall the module everytime I want to test or update?


Attempted to clone from bitbucket. That will pull the file but how can I have it as a global import.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I see 2 options:

package your modules (as local files)
use git submodules

Packaging modules locally
it is just like packaging to publish on pypi, without publishing it. Package to a wheel file and then pip install / upgrade the module every time you want to 'upgrade'.
It is clean and you can control what app uses what version of the module through the dependencies file, like any other. Easy.
Create a package like you would for pypi (see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)
Use submodules in git.
You can have submodules in your git repo that tracks external modules (repositories). Basically creating a 'folder' in your repo that maps to another repository. It is 'convenient', but I find that it is also easy to mess that up, as you need to pull the changes in submodules specifically (updates do not just show up because you pushed to the other repo). It's also tempting to make changes to the submodule code in your main repo directly, but then you need to make sure to track/commit these changes to the submodule; it's different from committing changes to your main repo. If you have multiple apps using the same submodule, and make changes in those, you often end up with out-of-sync changes and merge conflicts.
So my preference goes to packaging and re-installing when versions change.
You can have a folder structure, where your repos are at one level, with the commons modules as one folder, and point the dependency to the relative path.
When you install on your server you clone the repos with the same folder structure, and pip install deps pointing to the relative path.
Ideally, for deployment you have you one storage server to publish your private modules and pip install from there.
